# Gateway Timeout Error with Nginx reverse proxy to Apache on the same server

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I'm working with Ubuntu 16.04 ang Nginx running Port 80 and 443. I use Proxy_Pass to forward traffic to Apache listening on Port 8080. Both Nginx and Apache are on the same server.

**Problem is that Nginx can't seem to forward traffic to Apache.** I'm getting 504 Gateway Timeout Error. I can confirm that Apache is running and receiving traffic on Port 8080.

I use proxy_pass extensively in my setup. And the traffic forwarded to Apache on Port 8080 on a different server is working fine. My only issue is this one with the Apache running on the same server as Nginx.

I've tried to set Apache `listen 8080` and `listen 127.0.0.1:8080` but I get the same error.

In Nginx I used `proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;` and `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080` but the results are the same.

The only thing I find different is that if I run `netstat -tulpn` while Apache uses `listen 8080`, Port 8080 only appears in tcp6 as `:::8080`. It does not seem to be open in tcp (IPv4). But with `listen 127.0.0.1:8080` tcp (IPv4) specifically opens `127.0.0.1:8080` but not anymore in tcp6. If I understand this correctly, it should be open on both IPv4 and IPv6 with Local Address showing as `0.0.0.0:8080` in IPv4 and `:::8080`  in IPv6.

Note that Firewall is not enabled.

I've trying to go over my config but to no avail. My setup is working if I forward it to a different server. I think this is something port or binding related? But I can't seem to find the answer. Been Googling but could not find a solution.

Hope someone has an idea what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you're trying to connect to apache on 127.0.0.1:8080, you need to make sure that apache is listening on specifically IPv4, as you're trying to connect to it using IPv4.

If you want to use IPv6, then specify the IPv6 address on your reverse proxy.